# Change colour of supplementary column using factoextra in R

Tags: r, correspondence-analysis, factominer, factoextra

I am trying to change the colour used for the supplementary column in a correspondence analysis using `fviz_ca_col()`  from the package *factoextra*, but I do not seem to get any response when changing the colour from the default `col.col.sup = "darkred"`. Reproducible example:

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)

# Load example data
data("housetasks")

# Perform correspondence analysis
resca <- CA(housetasks, 
                 col.sup = which(names(housetasks) == "Alternating"),  
                 graph = FALSE)

# Call to plot
fviz_ca_col(resca, col.col.sup = "black")
```

The resulting plot has the supplementary column `"Alternating"` in the default dark red colour:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in the [source code](https://github.com/kassambara/factoextra/blob/master/R/fviz_ca.R#L200):

```
fviz (X, element = "col", axes = axes, geom = geom.col,
        color = col.col, alpha = alpha.col,
        pointshape = shape.col, select = select.col, 
        map = map, repel = repel, 
        colcol.sup = col.col.sup, shape.sup = shape.col, ...)
```

The input parameter should be `col.col.sup =`  instead of `colcol.sup =`

One way is to call fviz:

```
fviz(resca,element="col",col.col.sup="black")
```

[image]